# How to run testsuite for GCC?

Tags: 11.04, gcc

I'm a newbie in Linux. I have installed Ubuntu 11.04 (64 bit).

I want to install gfortran (GCC). They sugest to run testsuites first. Then I installed Dejagnu. I have found [some instructions here](http://pcc.ludd.ltu.se/standards_and_regression_testing/gcc_testsuite/)

I followed them. However, when trying

```
runtest --tool gcc --srcdir ./testsuite test/testfile.exp
```

I get

```
cannot trap SIGSEGV
    while executing
"trap { send_user "\nsegmentation violation\n"; exit 1 } SIGSEGV"
    (file "/usr/local/bin/../lib/dejagnu/runtest.exp" line 31)
```

Could you help me to get started with the gcc testsuite?

Answer (score 2):

In order to install [gfortran](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gfortran), you do not need to run any test suites. Just go to the software center, search for *gfortran* and install it (or click on the little package icon in the previous sentence).

Same goes for [dejagnu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/dejagnu). If you really need it you do not have to compile and install it yourself, just use Ubuntu's package manager.

You can find a lot of information on installing software for Ubuntu [here on the help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware)